# Problem getting charset working when moving database

Tags: php, collation, charset

Short. I am moving a database and webpage. It is now an exact copy but on the webpage it doesnt display the swedish characters correctly.

Example
`VÃƑÂ„RMARE` should be `VÄRMARE`
In the old database it is `VÃ„RMARE` in the new it is `VÃƒÂ„RMARE`

It is an old webpage on an old php version that when i am moving will be a much later php version and a `mariaDB`.

I think it has to do with the collation in the database for the tables but in `phpmyadmin 2.11.8.1` i can't se collation for the columns.

In the head i define

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I don't even know where to start troubleshooting.

Any suggestions how to troubleshoot would be amazing for me.

Comment: Phpmyadmin version 2 is really, *really* old. Current version is 5.1 . If you're using an old version of PHP there's **no excuse** for that, you really, really should be using PHP 5.6 or newer as an *ABSOLUTE* minimum, and using version 7.3 or later is highly recommended.

Comment: Yes that is what i aim for. The new host has PHP 7.4 and phpmyadmin 4.9.7. So it is much better.